# Net magnetic field & magnetization on a ferromagnetic material

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

A ferromagnetic materiel is saturated by an exterior magnetic field like so:

[image]

Where $B_1$ is a uniform magnetic field. Then after some time $t$ another magnetic field $B_2$ is introduced as well, but in a different direction:

[image]

**If $B_1$ is $3T$ and $B_2$ is $1.5T$ what is the resulting magnetization direction?**

**Also $B_2$ is not a uniform magnetic field, does that effect the magnetization of the material in anyway?**

I'm not certain of the net $\vec B $, and due to that the resulting magnetization of the sample.

Comment: Problems like this are best modeled numerically, unless you are extremely good with partial differential equations? There is plenty of magnetostatics software out there that can get you reasonable solutions, even for non-linear magnetic materials. For starters you could use FEMM:http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you! Been looking for a good software.